# Dowload additional Keyboard Layouts in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a Brazilian Keyboard that I need to use in my machine for some testing, but none of Brazilian Layouts that came with Ubuntu Lucid Lynx release are 100% compatible (I'm missing question marks and "/").

How do I download additional keyboard layouts? Is it possible? It's a HP KU-0316 model (Brazilian Version).

By the way, it's an english installation with a Brazilian keyboard. Does it have some effect in the problem I'm describing or shouldn't matter?

If it's not possible to download this keyboard layout, can I at least try to use an utility to "map" my failing keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seens everything is correct at Ubuntu, [I tested the question mark key with xev utility](https://superuser.com/questions/152738/how-to-debug-a-keyboard-in-linux-like-pressing-a-key-and-seeing-a-code-in-a-te) and it wasn't detected, so I don't think it's a problem with additional layout.