# How to "debug" a keyboard in Linux? Like pressing a key and seeing a code in a terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, debug

I didn't have an answer to my problem about [adding additional keyboards in my Ubuntu 10.04](https://superuser.com/questions/151463/dowload-additional-keyboard-layouts-in-ubuntu). Questions mark is not working in my keyboard, only using Alt Gr key + W.

So, I don't know if this is a problem with Ubuntu or Virtualbox itself (I'm running it inside a VM).

It's an usb keyboard. HP KU-0316.

I would like to debug this problem. The keyboard is plugged in, so when I press a key I believe **something** is being sent to my operating system, some code, I don't know. I would like to digg this problem, find some damn key code and find some damn *.conf file and manually fix my problem.

So, do an application like this exist in Linux?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try [`xev`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xev). It will display the keycodes that the X Window system sees when you press the keys you're interested in. You can use [`xmodmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xmodmap) to modify the mapping.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking for! And when I press the key, nothing shoes... maybe a Virtualbox bug?

Answer (score 23):

An awesome utility from linux-input called 'evtest' is excellent at debugging keyboard, mice, and joysticks. Function keys should work too.

```
apt-get install evtest
```

Sample output from pressing the caps lock key while evtest running:

```
Event: time 1398955189.226822, type 17 (EV_LED), code 1 (LED_CAPSL), value 1
Event: time 1398955189.226822, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70039
Event: time 1398955189.226822, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 58 (KEY_CAPSLOCK), value 0
Event: time 1398955189.226822, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Since evtest uses /dev/input, you can use it from a TTY or SSH, with no Xserver running.

Answer (score 6):

There are so-called *event device files* which are bound into a very low level of input layer. They reside in `/dev/input/` directory, and you can read keycodes that are passed by virtual PS/2 keyboard by doing `sudo hd /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd`. If this command fails, just try that with each of `/dev/input/eventX` files: one of them will be bound to your keyboard.

Comment: Any advice for when neither `sudo hexdump /dev/input/by-path/*-kbd` nor `sudo hexdump /dev/input/event*` has any output? My laptop keyboard works in BIOS but nowhere else. I can see output from the aforementioned commands only with my USB keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

There is `showkey`, which in Ubuntu is installed by default as part of the "kbd" package.

```
sudo showkey
```

(It exits after 10 seconds without a key being pressed, or with Ctrl-C)

There is also a quite complete list of possibilities in [this answer on "Unix & Linux"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120201/7286)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `libinput`:

1. Identify keyboard's input stream with `sudo libinput list-devices`, sample output (look into `Kernel:` value):

```
Device:           AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
Kernel:           /dev/input/event3
```

2. Debug keyboard with the following command (note
   `--show-keycodes` [parameter](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/libinput-tools/libinput-debug-events.1.en.html#show)): `sudo libinput debug-events --show-keycodes /dev/input/event3`

Example output:

```
-event3   DEVICE_ADDED            AT Translated Set 2 keyboard      seat0 default group1  cap:k
 event3   KEYBOARD_KEY            +2.327s       KEY_KP1 (79) pressed
1 event3   KEYBOARD_KEY            +2.415s      KEY_KP1 (79) released
 event3   KEYBOARD_KEY            +3.901s       KEY_1 (2) pressed
1 event3   KEYBOARD_KEY            +3.989s      KEY_1 (2) released
 event3   KEYBOARD_KEY            +4.632s       KEY_2 (3) pressed
2 event3   KEYBOARD_KEY            +4.720s      KEY_2 (3) released
 event3   KEYBOARD_KEY            +5.022s       KEY_3 (4) pressed
```