# Key is not detected in xev neither showkey -k in Ubuntu 10.04 in a Virtualbox VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, virtualbox

My question mark key in my keyboard isn't working. ("?"). I've tried to use [xev](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xev.1.html) and `showkey -k` to try to identify at least a keycode and manually use xmodmap to map it.

Unfortunately, the keys aren't being detected in neither utilities. I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 in a Virtual Machine (VirtualBox 3.2.4 r62467), and my Kernel is 2.6.32-22-generic. My Host is an Ubuntu 8.04.

When I run `xev` in my host, I get:

> ```
> KeyRelease event, serial 30, synthetic
> NO, window 0x3600001,
> root 0x5d, subw 0x0, time 19346721, (726,722), root:(730,746),
> state 0x2010, keycode 211 (keysym 0x2f, slash), same_screen YES,
> XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 61
> XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2f) "/"
> XFilterEvent returns: False
> ```

And when I run `showkey -v`:

> 0x59 0xd9

`xmodmap -pk` about this key in guest:

```
0x002f (slash)  0x003f (question)   0x002f (slash)  0x003f (question)   0x00b0 (degree) 0x00bf (questiondown)
```

...in host:

```
 0x002f (slash)  0x003f (question)   0x003b (semicolon)  0x003a (colon)  0xfe60 (dead_belowdot)  0xfe56 (dead_abovedot)
```

But when I click it on my guest it simply doesn't work.

Some related tickets in Virtualbox: [#4957](http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4957), [#599](http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/599) and [#205](http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/205).

What can this be? It's not a special multimedia key, it's a simple one. I would like to understand what exactly is happening so at least I can try to better debug this issue. If it's detected in my host, why it isn't in my guest?

Comment: Does `?` work on the console (Ctrl-Alt-1)? What keyboard layout do you have (US, European, etc.)? Does `showkey -k` show you any keys, but just not `?`; more data, please.

Comment: Couldn't test console mode in the VM, how do you do it in Virtualbox?. I have a Brazilian Keyboard layout, it's an HP model (KU-0316). showkey -k shows any keys, just not ?. http://superuser.com/questions/151463/dowload-additional-keyboard-layouts-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I give up.

I'm going to buy a new keyboard. $10 for my sanity. I've already learned a bunch of xmodmap concepts and such.

Comment: Did you see the answer above?

Comment: Yep. But I don't even have that Virtual Machine anymore, so it's not worth the hassle and I can't test your solution (although "If nothing new appears in dmesg then your key does not have a scancode, which means that it is not recognized by the kernel and cannot be used.", I only mark as accepted if I can test for sure). But thanks for passing by, your post may me useful for someone! +1

Answer (score 8):

From [archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_Keyboard_Keys#Check_for_scancodes):

> **Check for scancodes**
>
> If a key does not have a keycode you can know if it has a scancode by
> looking at the kernel log using the dmesg command:
>
> ```
> $ dmesg|tail -5
> ```
>
> If when you press the key something like that appears:
>
> ```
> atkbd.c: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xf1 on isa0060/serio0).
> atkbd.c: Use 'setkeycodes e071 <keycode>' to make it known.
> ```
>
> then your key has a scancode which can be mapped to a keycode. See [Map scancodes to keycodes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_Keyboard_Keys#Check_for_scancodes).
>
> If nothing new appears in dmesg then your key does not have a
> scancode, which means that it is not recognized by the kernel and
> cannot be used.

Comment: My key is being listet by `showkey` but not in `dmesg`.

Answer (score 0):

I've spend alot of time binding a detectable but unable to get correct keycode. This is the easiest way I found to detect and bind it.
Use :

```
xbindkeys -k
```

Install xbindkeys if not installed. And then enter above command, then enter the key you want to know the keycode. You'll get keycode and key name with it like this,

```
m:0x10 + c:169
Mod2 + XF86AudioPlay
```

Then use xmodmap to bind the key with the keyname(you can search the keyname in the list by using following command xmodmap -pk). In my case I wanted to bind this key with Super key.

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 169 = Super_L"
```

Hope this helps!